# PHP contact form linebreak issue

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have a PHP contact form on my website. I have been using it for about a year now without any problems. Nothing has been updated on my website that has do to with the contact form. However, all of a sudden, when a user enters "line breaks" or "paragraphs" in the message box, when I receive the message, instead of having several paragraphs I have 1 long paragraph with "\r\n" in place of line breaks.

Here is the code:

```
$to = "info@mycompany123.com";
$headers = "From: $email";
$subject = $subject;
$body = "Name: $name\n\n"
. "Email: $email\n\n"
. "Subject: $subject\n\n"
. "Message: $message" ;

mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
```

I really do not know why it started doing this out of the blue but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the code. If you see `\r\n` literally in the code, you may have single quotes where double should be, or various other possible problems.

Comment: has some one gone and done something stupid like turn on safe_mode ?

Comment: @Dragon I just checked my php.ini file and safe_mode is "Off". Any other ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: You don't say what operating system this is runing on nor which MTA you are using nor how PHP connects to the MTA. SMTP expects lines to be terminated with \r\n but you seem to be using \n\n. In some cases the MTA (or the client) will handle this translation for you. Usually when you've got a problem sending mail via PHP the problem is with the MTA / config - not the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to convert your message using the `nl2br($row['message']);` function when you are displaying the messages.

$row['message'] is just an example, it can be any string.

Comment: This did not work for me. Instead of showing "\r\n" it replaced it with "<br />". Any other ideas?

Comment: I think that could work if he was using html email. But looks like plain text email to me.

Comment: @Gohn67 Yes it is plain text email.